# Unhandled exceptions in a RESTful API are not getting jsonify'ed

Tags: python, rest, exception, resources, flask

I have the following code - It has a http handler function `(func1)` and a RESTful API `(func2)` and they are reachable through URLs `/test1` and `/test2`. I have a exception handler function `(exception_handler)` which is decorated by `app.errorhandler()` to ensure that all unhandled exceptions are jsonify'ed and sent back as response.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask.ext.restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def exception_handler(e):
  return jsonify(reason=e.message), 500

@app.route("/test1", methods=["GET"])
def func1():
    raise Exception('Exception - test1')

class func2(Resource):
  def get(self):
    raise Exception('Exception - test2')

api.add_resource(func2, '/test2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now converting an unhandled exception to a HTTP response with a JSON containing exception message works fine for a normal http handler function i.e. `func1` but the same does not work for a RESTful API (created using Resource) i.e `func2`.

The following works fine as expected with `func1`:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/test1 -X GET
{
  "reason": "Exception - test1"
}
```

With `func2` we are getting a `{"message": "Internal Server Error", "status": 500}` instead of `{"reason": "Exception - test2"}`

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/test2 -X GET
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500
}
```

So the question is why the unhandled exceptions in RESTful API is not converted to JSON using `app.errorhandler`? or is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Error handling in FR is too limited in my opinion. Also see https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful/pull/284.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This because `Flask-Restful` monkeypatch default [`Flask.handle_user_exception`](https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L95) which will have [specific logic for `Flask-Restful` endpoints](https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L144) and default behaviour for other endpoints.

Comment: @sangeeth-saravanaraj So, what kind of solution did you use?

Comment: I do not remember now, but probably you can use override error_router/handle_error: https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/4e45f1ac39c8fb90104f825967aec9b802b7f760/flask_restful/__init__.py#L248, or send there some handlers like Api.__init__(error=YOUR THERE). Please check documentation for this case.

Answer (score 3):

Flask-Restful has its own error handler, the JSON output that you are seeing from `/test2` is being generated by the extension itself.

You can override Flask-Restful's exception if you register a new exception handler via Flask's [handle_exception](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.handle_exception) call.

Comment: Miguel, could you be a little more specific? How could we override Flask-Restful's exception handling and so to say re-activate Flask's vanilla exception handling for a certain exception type?

Comment: Take a look at how Flask-Restful [redirects error handling through itself](https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful/blob/4e45f1ac39c8fb90104f825967aec9b802b7f760/flask_restful/__init__.py#L192). In the same way they replace the error handler so that they are called before Flask, you can insert your own error handler that is called before Flask-Restul's. In your handler you can decide when you pass the error to Flask-Restful and when you handle it yourself. If you want to call Flask's original handler, then make a copy of this handler before registering Flask-Restful.